# PHP PDO Check if database query returns NULL values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP function that makes a query to the database. I want if the query returns NULL Values the function to return false. `empty($result) does not work.`

```
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
    $query->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $result = $query->execute();
    if ($result) {
        if ($isVitamin) {
            $result_table = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result_table['isVitamin'] = 1;
            if (empty($result)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return $result_table;
            }
        } else {
            $result_table = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (empty($result)) {
                return false;
            } else {
            //  echo "inside else";
            //  echo $result_table['name'];
                $result_table['isVitamin'] = 0;
                return $result_table;
            }
        }
    }  else {
        return false;
    }
```

Query returns null values. Function does not return FALSE

[image]

Comment: Try to use is_null() function instead.

Comment: Please, whenever possible post error messages as text and not as screenshots. This helps considerably with readability and searching. It's also kind of terrifying that you have w3schools in your bookmarks bar as that resource is [quite hazardous](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: I agree! Its there since my first year in university (now 5th) :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are using "$result" where you should be using "$result_table" - check the comment below:

```
$query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$result = $query->execute();
if ($result) {
    if ($isVitamin) {
        $result_table = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result_table['isVitamin'] = 1;
        if (empty($result)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $result_table;
        }
    } else {
        $result_table = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (empty($result)) { //<-- this should be $result_table ?
            return false;
        } else {
        //  echo "inside else";
        //  echo $result_table['name'];
            $result_table['isVitamin'] = 0;
            return $result_table;
        }
    }
}  else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That was the mistake... My bad

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
    If(empty($result))
Use
    If(!$result)